# if i put number 1 in cell C6 then -35 or if i put 2 in cell C6 then +35

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to add and minus the number from Cell `E9` to display in Cell `E8` e.g if i type number 1 in cell `C6` then -35 or if i type number 2 in Cell `C6` then +35 to the cell `E9` to display in cell `E8`. Here is my formula below it works with number 1 but not with number 2.

```
=E9-IF(C6=1,35,IF(C6=2,+35))
```

Why does the formula don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
=E9-IF(C6=1,35,IF(C6=2,-35))
```

The issue is that your take **-** IF, so no matter what, both of your previous values would have get you a minus sign (- x + = -). (35 & +35 is the same)

---

There is a really good funcion in Excel "Evaluate Formula", that has step-to-step progress how the formula evaluate the calculation progress.

In our case you will see that the original formula would have progressed like this:

Original excel formula (typed 2 in `C6`):

```
0-IF(C6=1,35,IF(C6=2,35))
```

Next step, since cell `C6` is 2, the first part of IF returns `FALSE`.

```
0-IF(FALSE,#N/A,IF(2=2,35))
```

Start evaluating next part (false part of IF, where 2=2 will be true)

```
0-IF(FALSE,#N/A,IF(TRUE,35))
```

The last part will give 35, but since you have minus:

```
0-IF(FALSE,#N/A,35)
```

You actually is arriving at the same number as the previous statement in the IF formula.

```
0-35
```

However,

if you set -35 in the last part `IF(C6=2,-35)` your final step will look like this:

```
0--35 -> 0+35
```

Comment: Thank you i couldn't do it with out you guys 